# polar chart heat map

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I was wondering if anyone could help me with making a polar heat map. To the template i chosen is http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/polar-coordinates-template/ what i would like to do is to colour the squares (like in darts) using colour scale from red to blue. the radius should be the x-axis, that is, the series of squares starting from inner circles to outer circles could be coloured according to some specified set of number values(1(blue)-1000(red)).  Am I making any sense?? also i don't need the grid.

thank you

Comment: Do you know [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)?